# angular 2+ search function without pipe

Tags: angular, search, input

I have 100+ results that I would like to be able to search without a pipe. Reason for not using pipe is that it reduces the performance to much.
The problem is that .indexOf returns read property 'indexOf' of undefined
error

Ideally I would like to show the results whilst typing (ie. two way binding?)

```html
    
<th class="header7"><input type="text" placeholder="search" 
  [(ngModel)]="filterString" (keyup)="applyfilter()"></th>

<div class="arrayOfGrade"
  *ngFor="let key of arrayOfGradedCoins; let i = index">


this.arrayOfGradedCoins[i] = 
  {"_id":key._id, "item1": this.item1,"item2": this.item2}


applyfilter = () => {
  var results =[];

  for (var i = 0; i<this.arrayOfGradedCoins.length; i++) {
    for (let key in this.arrayOfGradedCoins[i]) {
      if (this.arrayOfGradedCoins[key].indexOf(this.filterString) != -1) {
        results.push(this.arrayOfGradedCoins[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  this.arrayOfGradedCoins = results;
}
```

Comment: Your `this.arrayOfGradedCoins[key]` is an object and you are calling `indexOf(...)` on it. Did you mean to use one of its properties instead?

Comment: ah ok I see what you are saying, I tried without [key] get no errrors but my list of items does not display when searching. I like to specifically search for item1

Comment: If you provide more details around what `this.arrayOfGradedCoins` contains and what specifically on those objects you are searching on, we can offer you help on how to change your `applyFilter()` method.

Comment: this.arrayOfGradedCoins[i] = 
  {"_id":key._id, "jaguar": this.item1,"wheels": this.item2}
This is what it contains, item1 would be for instance a car-type. so when I search for jaguar it needs to show the iteration of this,arrayOfGradedCoins that has jaguar in it. So I am searching for just 1 property within an iteration. So jaguar might be i=1 porsche might be i=2. I then display the details of that particular iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you have in your comment, I'm assuming that you want to search on the keys from your object held in `this.arrayOfGradedCoins[i]`. Something along the lines of this should get you the results based off of this.

```js
const results = this.arrayOfGradedCoins.filter(c => {
    const keys = Object.keys(c).filter(k => k !=== '_id');
    return keys.find(k => ~k.indexOf(this.filterString));
});
```

Comment: I am sorry through trying the above I noticed that it didn't work, but then I also noticed that I made a mistake.

Comment: I am sorry through trying the above I noticed that I made a mistake, The array is actually: this.arrayOfGradedCoins[i] = {"_id":key._id, "car": "Jaquar","wheels": "michelin"} .  const results = this.arrayOfGradedCoins.filter(c => {
    const keys = Object.keys(c).filter(k => k !== '_id'); Console.log ( keys) gives me : ["car", "wheels"]  So if I type in jaguar in the search box, it should look at the key car and return me the index of the array it was found in. I am not sure how to loop over the arrayOfGradedCoins searching for the key car and then finding the value 'jaguar'

Comment: Change `keys.find(k => ~k.indexOf(this.filterString))` to `keys.find(k => ~c[k].indexOf(this.filterString))`

Comment: return keys.find(k => ~c[k].indexOf(this.filterString)) gives me error I am using Es6, maybe this is different.I get an error as per the attached picture. I am getting an error in my console: . When I add k => ~c[k].indexOf(this.filterString)) > 0 I am getting rid of the attached error message and it runs, however I then get this console error: c[k].indexOf is not a function

Comment: http://2ality.com/2013/12/array-prototype-find.html the answer probably lies here, but I find it hard to understand what they mean by predicate.  predicate(element, index, array)